# jLabel get text at point

Tags: java, jlabel, point

I have a JLabel and I want to get the text at a specific location using a mouselistener, so I want to get the **word** at a **point** on a **jLabel**.

I'm unsure if I'm able to use something else rather than a jLabel because I need html-compatibility and other conditions.

I tried to use a jTextArea once but I guess it didn't work as needed (I didn't work on the project for a while). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with `JLabel`, but it is possible with a `JTextComponent` (such as `JTextArea`), thanks to the `viewToModel()` method, which:

*Converts the given place in the view coordinate system to the nearest representative location in the model.*

So, inside you `MouseListener`:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   int index = textArea.viewToModel(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
   String text = textArea.getText();
   String word = "";
   int i = index;
   while(isWordChar(text.charAt(i))) // Get text after the index
      word += text.charAt(i++);
   i = index-1;
   while(isWordChar(text.charAt(i))) // Get text before the index
      word = text.charAt(i--) + word;
}
```

Comment: Well that doesn't work :( **isWordChar** is an unknown method and even if it works like that how am I able to change the colors of specific lines if html doesn't work with jTextAreas?

Comment: OK. `isWordChart` is a function you have to write to check if a character is a letter or a whitespace. I just gave you a general direction here. Indeed `JTextArea` is not compatible with *rendering* html. For that you need a `JTextPane`, which works in a similar way, but with many more options.